# Sass error installing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, rubygems

I have this message on mac High Sierra when i try to install sass

```
MBP-de-Patricia:~ patricia$ sudo gem install sass
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sass:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.23/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r 
./siteconf20180318-892-l1v6lp.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h
extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.23 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-17/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.23/gem_make.out
MBP-de-Patricia:~ patricia$
```

Comment: Check with `sass-rails` once.